# Why does this key exist in an empty Dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
sumDict = {}
n = 1000
print(sumDict)
for c in range(1,n):
    for d in range(1,n):
        result = c**3 + d**3
        if (result in sumDict):
            #print(1729 in sumDict)     #always true
            sumDict[result] = sumDict[result].append((c,d))
        else:
            sumDict[result] = [(c,d)]

for key,val in sumDict.items():
    for pair in val:
        for pair in val:
            print(pair,pair)]]
```

I'm trying to find all integer combinations that satisfy a^3 + b^3 = c^3 + d^3. I am mapping the result of c^3 + d^3 to a list of pairs that satisfy the sum. I always get the following error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Upon further investigation, the key 1729 always exists in the dictionary for some reason (unless I'm missing something). Can someone tell me what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary isn't empty at all. Your problem is occurring here:

```
sumDict[result] = sumDict[result].append((c,d))
```

Here you set `sumDict[result]` to `None`, because the return value of `list.append()` is `None`. The next time through the list, `result` is in the dictionary but the value associated with it is `None`, and you can't append to `None`.

Instead, simply write:

```
sumDict[result].append((c,d))
```

Or better yet, remove your `if` statement entirely and just write:

```
sumDict.setdefault(result, []).append((c, d))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        sumDict[result] = sumDict[result].append((c,d))
```

`append` returns None, so after this line executes, `sumDict[result]` will refer to `None` instead of the list that it used to refer to. Then the next time this line executes, it will try to call `append` on that None value, and crash.

Don't assign the result of `append` to anything, just call it.

```
        sumDict[result].append((c,d))
```